# AJAX: Can't pass javascript variable to SQL query in PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a PHP page with 2 sections side by side. The left pane has a MySQL query that runs and produces a list of categories as links. The right pane should have subcategories that appear when links in the left pane are clicked.

I have some AJAX in an attached JS file that should pass the ID in the links from the left pane, into a query in the right pane. The query should run. It runs if I take out a variable.

The PHP/SQL Queries work fine. JS does not.

I think this is the appropriate way of doing this.

**ajax.js**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$( 'a' ).on( 'click', function() {
    var a = $( this ).attr( 'id' );

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "categories.php",
        data: "ajax="+a,
        success: function(response){
            alert( a );
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Error');
        }
    })
});
```

});

I am being told everything works, but I cannot call `$_POST['ajax']` in PHP. Perhaps my page is not being refreshed. There is no form on the page.

Lastly, my file hierarchy has categories.php comprised of a list of includes, which are in a folder that is not public.

Comment: Try logging the response in your console. What do you see? And you should probably format your output form categories.php with JSON for better interoperability.

Comment: Perhaps I'm doing something incorrectly, but I only need the ajax call to get an attribute from a link, nothing directly from PHP. Only need it to run a dynamic query on a click even.

Answer (score 1):

I think your ajax syntax is wrong. Try this if your argument is `a` and your post identifier is `ajax`:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( 'a' ).on( 'click', function() {
        var a = $( this ).attr( 'id' );

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "categories.php",
            data: {ajax : a},
            success: function(response){
                alert( a );
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting async: false on your $.ajax call. Also, how is the data being return from php? Are you using JSON_ENCODE for the data?

Comment: My script generates a list of links to a page. JQuery pulls the id from the links and hopefully sends it to the page which will run an SQL query.